# Find the same date from two sets of data

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am new to Python. I got two sets of data shown as below.

Set 1:

```
Gmt time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,RSI,,Change,Gain,Loss,Avg Gain,Avg Loss,RS
15.06.2017 00:00:00.000,0.75892,0.76313,0.7568,0.75858,107799.5406,0,,,,,,,
16.06.2017 00:00:00.000,0.75857,0.76294,0.75759,0.76202,94367.4299,0,,0.00344,0.00344,0,,,
18.06.2017 00:00:00.000,0.76202,0.76236,0.76152,0.76188,5926.0998,0,,-0.00014,0,0.00014,,,
19.06.2017 00:00:00.000,0.76189,0.76289,0.75848,0.75902,87514.849,0,,-0.00286,0,0.00286,,,
...
```

Set 2:

```
Gmt time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
15.06.2017 00:00:00.000,0.75892,0.75933,0.75859,0.75883,4777.4702
15.06.2017 01:00:00.000,0.75885,0.76313,0.75833,0.76207,7452.5601
15.06.2017 02:00:00.000,0.76207,0.76214,0.76106,0.76143,4798.4102
15.06.2017 03:00:00.000,0.76147,0.76166,0.76015,0.76154,4961.4502
15.06.2017 04:00:00.000,0.76154,0.76162,0.76104,0.76121,2977.6399
15.06.2017 05:00:00.000,0.7612,0.76154,0.76101,0.76151,3105.4399
...
```

I want to find lines in Set 2 in the same date with Set 1. I tried this: `print(daily['Gmt time'][0].date == hourly['Gmt time'][0].date)`, but I don't know why it came out False. Isn't there a way to compare the date(just date, not including time) from two sets of data?

Comment: Load both the dataset pandas dataframe. change column datetime format to just date. compare for equality

Comment: @Vikash Singh Thanks but do I have to use dataframe to solve this?  And why the comparison came out false?

Comment: try this `print(daily['Gmt time'][0].date, hourly['Gmt time'][0].date)` this will clarify why the comparison came out false.

Comment: you can solve this without dataframe also, but your data is in tabular format. dataframes are good for handling tabular data.

Comment: @Vikash Singh I'll try to figure it out as you said. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Vikash Singh so sorry to bother you again but I'm not quite familiar with dataframe, could you tell me that how can I load these sets to data frame and change the column to just date?

Comment: sure, are the 2 data sets in files ??

Comment: what kind of comparison you want to do?? df_two has multiple times the date present in df_one.. how do you want to perform the comparison?

Comment: @Vikash Singh Thanks for all the efforts! I wish to find out the lines of in set 2 that has the same date with a line in set 1 since one is daily and one is hourly. for example I want to find the lines in set 2 that in 15.06.2017

Comment: @CG : updated my answer how you can compare. hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read the data sets into dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
df_one = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('data_set_one.csv', index_col=False)
df_two = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('data_set_two.csv', index_col=False)
```

Convert date column to date

```
df_one['Gmt date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_one['Gmt time']).dt.date
df_two['Gmt date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_two['Gmt time']).dt.date
```

now compare both the dataframes:

```
for i, row in df_one.iterrows():
    df_one_date = row['Gmt date']
    print('df_one_date', df_one_date)
    print(df_two[df_two['Gmt date'] == df_one_date])
    print('----')
```

it's still unclear how you want to handle for different dates from df_one to match df_two. Hope this gives you enough idea on how to handle it.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Since using iterrows can be slow, a better option might be to use merge.

```
import pandas as pd

# load data
df_one = pd.read_csv('data_set_one.csv', index_col=False)
df_two = pd.read_csv('data_set_two.csv', index_col=False)

# convert times to datetime and then strip off the time to leave the date
df_one['Gmt date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_one['Gmt time']).dt.date
df_two['Gmt date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_two['Gmt time']).dt.date

# merge
# selecting only the date in each dataframe for clarity
df_merge = df_two[['Gmt date']].merge(df_one[['Gmt date']], on=['Gmt date'], how='inner', right_index=True)

# get list of indices from df_two where dates exist in both frames
ix = list(df_two.index.unique())
print ix
```

> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it out later:D